# How to use custom utility classes in RDL?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, rdl, report-designer

how do you use your own utility classes (those you use in application code) in Microsoft reporting in local mode? Is it even possible?

I have read some specification and there are some elements that indicate it can be done but it is not really clear on what to do.

Simply calling the code does not work even if I call it with namespace prefix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have an assembly fully qualified as `ReportUtils, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null` with your utility methods.

It has 2 classes:

- public **static** class `ReportUtils.Foo` with a public method `string GetValue()`
- public class `Bar` with a parameterless constructor and a public property `Id`.

### Visual Studio 2008

`Report -> Report Properties -> References` - **References** section.

### RDL xml

add

```
<CodeModules>
    <CodeModule>ReportUtils, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null</CodeModule>
</CodeModules>
```

under the `Report` element.

You can also add **instances** of your classes that will get auto-constructed when you report is loaded:

### Visual Studio 2008

same menu as before - **Classes** section.

### RDL xml

add

```
<Classes>
    <Class>
        <ClassName>ReportUtils.Bar</ClassName>
        <InstanceName>barInstance</InstanceName>
    </Class>
</Classes>
```

under the `Report` element.

You can use your static utility method like this:

```
<Value>=ReportUtils.Foo.GetValue()</Value>
```

You can use your class instance like this:

```
<Value>=Code.barInstance.Id</Value>
```

You have to add your assembly as trusted to the `LocalReport` instance you are using:

```
localReport.AddTrustedCodeModuleInCurrentAppDomain("ReportUtils, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
```

You may have to copy your `ReportUtils` assembly to your *VS2008\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies* directory so you can design your reports in Visual Studio's report designer without errors.

I have used this recently so this should be all the necessary steps to achieve your goal.

Comment: I had to have copy of my assembly inside
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\